# Android app providing core services to other apps

Tags: java, android

This is enterprise android app, We have many applications in pipeline and we don't want to repeat some horizontal concerns like communicating to our backend servers, securing the data, single sign-on, sending current state of app etc. 
We are thinking if we can develop an app which takes care of all these cross cutting concerns and other apps only utilize the services provided by these apps. Is this feasible ? Is this design ok or there should be other approach to solve this problem.

Just pointers can be enough :) I can figure out the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this feasible ?

It is technically possible. However:

- When the user uninstalls this magic app, all the other apps break
- Securing the IPC to the magic app is doable (use `signature`-level permissions) but important

Usually, you don't create an app to address "horizontal concerns" -- you create a library. This is true for most operating systems and development frameworks that I have ever encountered, anyway. In Android's case, that would either be a JAR (if it is pure code) or an Android library project (if it needs resources).

Comment: A library doesn't address the issue of sharing data between the apps (e.g. authentication details for single-sign on network services, and so on).

Comment: @Jules: "A library doesn't address the issue of sharing data between the apps" -- sure it can. Use an election protocol for dynamically choosing the "magic app" that is the central repository of transient data. That way, even if today's "magic app" is uninstalled, a re-election can designate another app to fill that role. Admittedly, securing this gets trickier than a single magic app, but, then again, I'm skeptical that Android's process model will allow for a well-written single-sign-on-across-N-apps implementation in the first place.

Comment: I've never tried this, but AIUI it is possible to request that multiple apps signed with the same developer key are installed with the same user id, at which point they could share files.  I'm not sure what happens on removal though -- I would presume that all files persist until the last application with the same uid is deleted, but this is definitely not something I've played with so I'm a long way from certain this would work.

Comment: @Jules: "it is possible to request that multiple apps signed with the same developer key are installed with the same user id, at which point they could share files" -- yes, but bear in mind that you cannot change the user ID, and so you have to set this up before you first ship the app. On the whole, this is considered to be a risky technique. Plus, the files still have to be stored *somewhere*, and if that's internal storage for one app, those files go "poof" once that app is uninstalled.